# Updating fancybox after loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I am making an ajax call on a button click. A `jspf` is returned as a response to this. 
I am opening this response(`jspf`) in a fancybox. Now, I have another requirement that is, to update certain portion of this fancybox with a response from another ajax call. 
the response to this second ajax call comes back and it gets populated into an empty `<div>`(which is already on the `jspf` i.e., the fancybox).

My problem now is to update the fancybox which is already open with the response from the second ajax call I am making. Can anyone please tell me how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery.append()

```
$('.fancybox div').append(data);
```

http://api.jquery.com/append/